# Как добавить "живой поиск" к ajax форме? asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

есть вот такая ajax-форма

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("FilterSearch", "EventDetails", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "thisplace"}))
    {
        <div class="form-group1" id="search" >
            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">A word or phrase to search:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Filter.SearchingItem, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Enter to search.." } })
            </div>
        </div>
<input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

по нажатию кнопки Search ищем информацию и выводим её. Как сделать так чтобы оно искало еще во время ввода данных в поле, без нажатия кнопки поиска?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#search input').on('keyup', function() {
  // Здесь вызвать поиск
});
```

Смысл в том, что вам просто нужно отловить event на изменение значения в вашем input.

on.('change') здесь не подойдет, т.к. он сработает только после .blur на вашем input.

on.('keydown') так же не подойдет, т.к. он будет срабатывать на 1 символ раньше - если в input значение 123 и вы жмете 4, то сначала обрабатывается ваш keydown, а только потом меняется значение в input.

и для отправки формы:

```
$('#search input').on('keyup', function () {
    $("#Filter_SearchingItem").submit();
});
```

Comment: да, это то что мне нужно, спасибо, но как вызвать поиск на С# через jquery? точнее как вызвать я уже разобрался, но как передать введенные данные

Comment: с C# я не работал, к сожалению, и смогу помочь только с jquery. Можешь посмотреть в сторону $.ajax() для отправки данных. Если поле одно, то можно просто на твой input повесить id и взять его значение:
$('input#your_id').val(); - здесь будут введенные данные.

Если больше, чем одно поле - погугли .serializeArray и new FormData

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, я добавил в ваш ответ решение!

Comment: Спасибо и вам за это :)